# Autoexecutable program on HID memory stick

Tags: python, c++, usb, hid

I am concepting an HID usb device which should be able to autoexecute a little Python/C++/(...) login program when connected to a computer, to allow the user to enter a password to access the content of the memory stick.
Any idea how to start with or what should I consider for this program?

Important:

- OS will be Windows (probably 8+) **and** Linux (probably CentOS)
- Computers will not have any program installed to interact with this usb device.
- It is all about just and only the usb device.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Answer will be OS specific, which OS ?

Comment: @RichardCritten good point! i updated my question... :-)

Comment: Reminder:  Python is *interpreted*, so you will need to place the Python interpreter on the HID.  C++ compiles into an executable, so you don't need an interpreter.

Comment: You have 2 problems - (1) how will a program of any type be started (by the OS) and (2) what type should the program be?.  I think problem (1) is unsurmountable because auto-run from removable media is a well known malware vector and all OSs I can think of have this (auto-run) disabled by default .

Comment: @RichardCritten (1) the USB device will have HID functionality, so it should be capable of "typing" in the console the commands to run its program, and (2) it will probably be a C++ compiled for Windows and for Linux

Comment: For Windows have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/plug-and-play-support

Answer (score 0):

1. User inserts USB device to PC
2. PC recognizes the USB device as a memory disk

   - The memory disk is empty (because password not entered) except
   - Only a file named `enter-password.txt`
3. User opens `enter-password.txt` and enters the password and saves
4. Real contents in the memory disk appear on the fly

It's compatible to all OS and no program is required in advance in PC.

Comment: thanks, however, I don't get it... (1) the device is not a memory stick but will be recognized as an HID device like a mouse or a keyboard, (2) I want a program to autorun when connecting the device to the bay and not having the user to open himself a file, (3) I don't get how writing and saving a pssw in a text file can be recognized / verified unless you have already opened another program which checks it, (4) anyway your text-file idea seems to me very security questionable... thanks for your hints and please elaborate if you think I might have not correctly understood your explanations :-)

Comment: You have said that `Computers will not have any program installed to interact with this usb device`, then where is the `a program to autorun`?

Comment: `inside` the Usb device

Comment: Do you mean HID device and Memory stick are two devices?

Comment: The device is an HID microcontroller with a memory card. You connect to the Usb  port and then I expect to run automatically a program requesting the user to log on

Comment: Do you mean your device includes two logical devices 1) the HID device 2) the memory card. These 2 devices share one USB connector to communicate with PC.

Comment: Yes... when the user logged on successfuly then should be able to access the SD card as standard

Comment: Because your autorun program is on device, i have no idea about how to let user input password in PC.

Comment: it's ok, thanks for trying anyway! :-)